# Source Control for CM users

Tags: version-control

I'm looking to stear my team into this century and use source control. The developers are very capable of handling source control software - be it command line based or GUI based, Windows or -Nix.

The reason they've been locally and individually handling their code (which deeply frightens me) is because our CM group is not as technically savvy nor comfortable with the whole check-in/out process.

> Is there a source control software out there that is geared towards the CM group? I'm thinking of one that would allow them to select a version of a file out of all that have been checked in and mark it for the build they are trying to create.

Comment: That is "CM group"? Which build-workflow you use now?

Comment: developers develop and save their files in their location of choice. When we need a build, CM asks the developers where the latest version is, copies that directory (or individual file if that be the case) to a new directory with the name of the build and then builds based on those files.

Comment: I think you have to start from establishing **good workflow of development** first before choosing SCM. Current *"unmanaged anarchy"* is just terrible. After is almost any SCM (maybe DVCS, because they support more types of flexible workflow) will fit your needs

Comment: believe you me, I agree completely - we're still working on improving the workflow, but i'm trying to look ahead at the SCM side.

I've just looked into DVCS and found a great tutorial that I plan on using should we go towards Mercurial: [Hg Init](http://hginit.com/)
(some of the developers have used Subversion in the past)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the CM (configuration Management) group as in charge of a release management process, then you could isolate them from the "technical details" of any (D)VCS tool you might choose by establishing a good publication process.

The **publication** consists of making visible somewhere (a shared directory, an artifact repository like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), dedicated to releases, ...):

- a deliver (a set of binary and their dependencies) necessary to run your program
- a clear list of versions for those binaries (SVN revision number or tag, git tag, Nexus Group-Artifact-Version, ...) allowing the developers to find the exact set of code whenever the CM group get back to them with a list of defect to fix
- a document explaining the deployment

The CM group take that set of deliveries, manages the release process and the promotion between the different deployment environment (Integration, UAT, pre-prod, prod, ...), without having to deal with the VCS tool.

That also enforces a strong separation between dev and prod (both in term of environment *and* process), which allows for the devs to adopt whatever workflow of development they want, withtout affect the way the CM group works.

Comment: Wow. Nexus sounds exactly like what I'm looking for; assuming you've used Nexus, how easy was it for you to get things set up (moving the files in, setting up users, etc)?

Comment: @redhotspike fairly easy, once you understand the idea (the Nexus book helps: http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/). What is very easy is when you store too much binaries: Nexus referential is a a collection of directories with a naming convention, so removing stuff is straightforward (as opposed to removing version in a VCS database).